# How include an activation link in my mail with FOSUserBundle?

Tags: swift, symfony, email, fosuserbundle, activation

I know it is possible to send a confirmation email with an activation lein through fosuserbundle. Only, I wish I could insert it myself when I want it.

I have users who make account creation requests, and I have to accept them (or refuse) manually. If I accept them, they receive an email with their credentials using SwiftMail. But I would also like to be able to insert this famous activation link so that when they click on it, it passes the "Enabled" variable of the User entity to true.

Currently, I can:

Recover the user I want to process, as well as his information.
Create an email and send it to him through the SwiftMail service, by sending him his credentials.

All I have to do is add a function or something that would allow me, in this email, to create an activation link specific to the user.

My code :

**In my Controller.php:**

```
$prenom  = $user->getPrenom();
$nom     = $user->getNom();
$email   = $user->getEmail();

$this->sendMail($prenom,$nom);
```

Return to this function:

```
public function sendMail($prenom,$nom,$email)
    {
        $transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance();

                // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
                $mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);

                $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                                ->setSubject("subject of the mail")
                                ->setFrom(array('*******' => '*****'))
                                ->setTo($email)
                                ->setCharset('utf-8')
                                ->setContentType('text/html')
                                ->setBody($this->renderView("@Pages/swiftmail/activation.html.twig",array(
                                    'prenom'=>$prenom,
                                    'nom'=>$nom,
                                )));

        $mailer->send($message);
    }
```

And the body of my email in **activation.html.twig** :

```
<p>Bonjour {{prenom}} {{nom}},</p>

<p>Votre compte a bien été validé.</p>

<p><i>Votre identifiant de connexion est : <b>{{login}}</b></i><br/>
<i>Votre mot de passe est : <b>{{mdp}}</b></i></p>

<p>Ce compte sera automatiquement désactivé après 400 jours ou après le téléchargement des paquets d'installation.</p>
<p>Cordialement,</p>

<span style="font-size:9px"><em>Ce mail a été généré automatiquement, merci de ne pas y répondre.</em></span><br/><br/>
```

So it's in activation.html.twig that I'd like to insert something to generate a user-specific activation link (using a function?). By passing in parameter the user object, I wonder if FOSUserBundle makes it possible to do what I ask?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so we both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: You might want to script the alternative yourself?

Comment: It's edited :) !